# Unused args[] for include of

Tags: ros, turtlebot, vlp16

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All the arguments are declared prior, but i still receive the same error. couldn't figure out why

```
unused args [device_ip, manager, port] for include of [/opt/ros/indigo/share/velodyne_driver/launch/nodelet_manager.launch]
```

please fnd my xml file below

```
<launch>

  <!-- declare arguments with default values -->


  <arg name="calibration" default="$(find velodyne_pointcloud)/params/VLP16db.yaml"/>
  <arg name="device_ip" default="" />    
  <arg name="frame_id" default="velodyne" />  
  <arg name="manager" default="$(arg frame_id)_nodelet_manager" />
  <arg name="max_range" default="130.0" />
  <arg name="min_range" default="0.4" />
  <arg name="pcap" default="" />
  <arg name="port" default="2368" />
  <arg name="read_fast" default="false" />
  <arg name="read_once" default="false" />
  <arg name="repeat_delay" default="0.0" />
  <arg name="rpm" default="600.0" />

  <!-- start nodelet manager and driver nodelets -->

  <include file="$(find velodyne_driver)/launch/nodelet_manager.launch">

    <arg name="device_ip" value="$(arg device_ip)"/> 
    <arg name="frame_id" value="$(arg frame_id)"/> 
    <arg name="manager" value="$(arg manager)" />
    <arg name="model" value="VLP16"/>
    <arg name="pcap" value="$(arg pcap)"/>
    <arg name="port" value="$(arg port)"/>
    <arg name="read_fast" value="$(arg read_fast)"/>
    <arg name="read_once" value="$(arg read_once)"/>
    <arg name="repeat_delay" value="$(arg repeat_delay)"/>
    <arg name="rpm" value="$(arg rpm)"/>

  </include>

  <!-- start cloud nodelet -->
  <include file="$(find velodyne_pointcloud)/launch/cloud_nodelet.launch">
    <arg name="calibration" value="$(arg calibration)"/>
    <arg name="manager" value="$(arg manager)" />
    <arg name="max_range" value="$(arg max_range)"/>
    <arg name="min_range" value="$(arg min_range)"/>
  </include>

</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257517/unused-args%5B%5D-for-include-of/) by [moksgo](https://answers.ros.org/users/29610/moksgo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2017-03-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My bad.. I am new to ROS and hence couldn't figure this out previously.

when we `<include ...>` a file as in the above case, we are passing all the parameters that are mentioned in the `<include >......</include>`  to be used in the file. (In this case, nodelet_manager.launch.) When we don't refer or use them in that file, this unused args issue will comeup.. .May be one of the cases where this issue might come up

---

Originally posted by [moksgo](https://answers.ros.org/users/29610/moksgo/) with karma: 48 on 2017-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-07-20**:
I'm not sure that I'm understanding this answer. Are you saying that you get the `unused args` warning because you're not using the args? From the looks of the launch file that you posted, you are using them.